# What I can do? in this error Fastlane [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - UploadException:ADHOC_PACKAGE_NAME_MISMATCH [[]]

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

I use two `build varient` debug and release.

I want to test uploading release bundle by internal test using below command

> fastlane internal

but the error above like title.

the package name is different with my intention and process.

I use `bundleRelease` so it would use *MY_RELEASE_PACKAGE_NAME* package name.

But Why the error occur with *MY_DEBUG_PACKAGE_NAME*` ?

How to solve this error?

```
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
|                        fastlane summary                        |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                    | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                          | 0           |
| 2    | clean bundleRelease                       | 135         |
|    | upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing | 9           |
+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

> Fastlane [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - UploadException:ADHOC_PACKAGE_NAME_MISMATCH [[]] MY_DEBUG_PACKAGE_NAME

when add `--verbose`

```
INFO [2021-10-12 12:19:54.38]: -------------------------------------------------------
INFO [2021-10-12 12:19:54.38]: --- Step: upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing ---
INFO [2021-10-12 12:19:54.38]: -------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG [2021-10-12 12:19:54.38]: Fetching a new access token from Google...
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/usr/local/bin/fastlane)
FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneError: [!] Google Api Error: Invalid request - UploadException: ADHOC_PACKAGE_NAME_MISMATCH [[]] (MY_DEBUG_PACKAGE_NAME)
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:141:in `user_error!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:95:in `rescue in call_google_api'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:80:in `call_google_api'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/client.rb:355:in `upload_apk_to_internal_app_sharing'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/uploader.rb:56:in `block in perform_upload_to_internal_app_sharing'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/uploader.rb:55:in `each'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/supply/lib/supply/uploader.rb:55:in `perform_upload_to_internal_app_sharing'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing.rb:32:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/one_off.rb:42:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/one_off.rb:22:in `execute'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:225:in `block (2 levels) in run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:117:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:353:in `run'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:42:in `start'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.195.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Fastfile

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play Internal Test"
  lane :internal do
    gradle(task: "clean bundleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store_internal_app_sharing aab:MY_AAB_PATH
  end

end
```

Appfile

```
json_key_file("fastlane/access_play_console.json") # 
package_name(MY_RELEASE_PACKAGE_NAME) # e.g. com.krausefx.app
```

Comment: do you have solution for this? @liveAnyway

Comment: Not yet. I don't konw why.

Comment: i just found this solution : https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19453#issuecomment-939339751 @liveAnyway

Comment: My case seems  different case with the github.